# Кнопка на весь экран

Tags: java

Уважаемые программисты, помогите!
Столкнулся с такой проблемой - кнопка создалась на весь фрейм, а при его расширении(изменении размера) кнопка меняет тоже! Подскажите, как исправить?

```
package ru.cherkasovs;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JFrame{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private int rayon = 1;
    private static JButton Button1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("");

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(479,597);
        f.add(new Map());
        f.setVisible(true);

         JPanel p = new JPanel(); 
            f.add(p);

            p.add(new JButton("Okay"), BorderLayout.NORTH);

            Button1 = new JButton("");
            f.add(Button1);
            JButton button = new JButton("Click me!");
            button.setVisible(true);
            button.setLocation(50, 50);
            button.setSize(50,50);
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Button1, "Don't touch me!",
                        "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
               }

            });
            f.add(new Map());
              f.add(Button1);

              f.add(Button1);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед добавлением кнопки добавьте AbsoluteLayout на весь Frame